# How to add a hyphen after every fifth character of a word in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Given `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXY"`

How does one achieve this outcome? `"ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY"`

Comment: What did you try and what's not working for you?

Comment: I still dont understand how to use awk or sed

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the reference, I would read that!

Comment: `N` is missing in the given string but magically appears in the hyphened version!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With sed you can do this by first adding a `-` after every 5 characters, then removing the trailing `-` at the end of the line:

```
$ sed -E 's/.{5}/&-/g; s/-$//' <<<"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY"
ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
```

In extended (`-E`) mode:

- `.{5}` matches any 5 characters
- `&-` replaces with the whole match (the 5 characters) plus `-`

Then the second substitution command matches `-` at the end of the line (`$`) and replaces with nothing.

---

With GNU awk, one option would be to use `FPAT` to define the way the line is interpreted as a series of fields, then add `-` between each field:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='.{5}' -v OFS='-' '{ $1 = $1 } 1' <<<"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY"
ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
```

The field pattern `FPAT` is defined as any 5 characters and the Output Field Separator `OFS` is defined as `-`. `$1 = $1` "touches" every line, causing it to be reformatted (without this part, nothing would happen). `1` is the shortest *true* condition causing each line to be printed.

---

It's not too difficult to do this in bash either:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY"
parts=()
# build an array from slices of length 5
for (( i = 0; i < ${#input}; i += 5 )) do
  parts+=( "${input:i:5}" )
done

# join the array on IFS (use a subshell to avoid modifying IFS for rest of script)
( IFS=-; echo "${parts[*]}" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
echo "ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXY" | sed 's/...../&-/g;s/-$//'
```

Comment: plus 1 from  my side

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for only letters will be

```
sed -E 's/[A-Z]{4}./&-/g' file.txt
```

The output will be:

```
ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMOP-QRSTU-VWXY
```

if you want them to include more than capital letters just do a:

```
sed -E 's/[A-Za-z]{4}./&-/g' file.txt
```

Comment: @PesaThe accurate sir

Answer (score 1):

Yet another choice

```
perl -pe 's/(.{5})(?=.)/$1-/g' file
```

Match 5 characters that are followed by another character (to avoid the trailing hyphen problem)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

s="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY"
a=($(echo ${s} | grep -o .))

o=""
i=0
while [[ ${i} -lt ${#a[@]} ]]; do
    o="${o}${a[${i}]}"
    (( i++ ))
    [[ $(( i % 5 )) -eq 0 ]] && [[ ${i} -ne ${#a[@]} ]] && o="${o}-"
done
echo ${o}

exit 0
```

Comment: While this works it's unbelievably convoluted, and could do with an explanation ;)

Comment: Understood.  Sorry for not adding comments originally.  :)

Comment: The line starting with "a" is converting the string "s" into an array.  The line starting with "o" is initializing an empty string.  The "o" variable will contain the output.  The line starting with "i" is initializing the index variable.  This will be used in the while loop to go through all of the elements in the array.  The array is indexed starting at 0.  The while loop conditional is just making sure that all elements in the array have been processed.  The "${#a[@]}" returns the number of elements in the array.  The first line within the loop is appending to "o"

Comment: The "(( i++ ))" is incrementing the index variable.  The next line is doing a modulus operation.  If "i" is a multiple of 5, and it is not at the end of the array, append a dash "-" to the output.  Once the loop has been processed, print out the resultant output string.

Comment: @Lewis you should add the explanation to your answer, rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

another solution with `fold/paste`

```
$ echo {A..Y} | tr -d ' ' |    # this is to generate the string
  fold -w5 | paste -sd-

ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.\{5\}\B/&-/g' file
```

Insert a hyphen every five characters as long as the fifth character is inside a word.